# Basic AND Probability from Given Data

Tags: probability

> In a particular week, the probability of a household purchasing cheese in any week was $20\%$ in England and $10\%$ in the rest of the UK. $75\%$ of the households sampled were in England.
>
> Calculate the probability that a randomly selected household from the sample is not England and did not buy cheese.

From data:

where $C$ is the event of buying cheese and $E$ the event of living in England,

$P(E)=0.75$   and $P(E')=0.25$

$P(C\mid E)=0.2$ and $P(C\mid E')=0.1$

Find $P(C'\cap E')$

as $P(C\mid E')=0.1,\, P(C'\mid E')=1-0.1=0.9$

$P(C'\cap E')=P(C'\mid E')P(E')$

$=0.9 \times 0.25=0.225$

The issue is my textbook says $P(C'\cap E')=0.025$ ????

Have I made a mistake or is the textbook wrong?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine polling 1000 people.  75%, so 750 people, are from England, 250 are not.  Of the 250 not from England, 10%, 25 purchase cheese, 225 do not.  Of the 1000 people, 225 are not from England and did not purchase cheese so the probability a person polled is not from England and did not purchase cheese is 225/1000= 0.225 or 22.5%.

Answer (score 2):

Your textbook has an error.  The answer is for the question "what is the probability that a randomly selected household is not from England and did buy cheese?"